# How can I permanently save Word Options / AutoCorrect settings via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have written a simple PowerShell script to edit the `$Word.AutoCorrect` and `$Word.Options` settings for table cells, but this setting appears to only last the length of the word process that is instantiated by the PowerShell script. How can I persist these settings?

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
# $Word.Visible = $True
$Word.AutoCorrect.CorrectTableCells = $False
$Word.Quit()
```

Using the `$Word.Visible = $True` I can verify that the setting is changing (and not quitting word), but next time I open Word outside of PowerShell the setting is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify `normal.dotm` which lies in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\`. This will only apply to new documents. For existing documents you'll need to attach your modified template to them.
Some more info [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e6fc870-8929-4dca-9d51-e4b168533ebf/making-permanent-changes-to-word-options?forum=officeitpro)

To save the normal.dotm from PowerShell simply call `$Word.NormalTemplate.Save()` i.e.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.AutoCorrect.CorrectTableCells = False
$Word.NormalTemplate.Save()
$Word.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been useful, but didn't entirely answer the question. I've been able to do this now in PowerShell thanks to your helpful pointer. All I needed was `$Word.NormalTemplate.Save()` before Word quits.

Comment: Thanks for your addition!